# Pybind Numpy access 2D / ND arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, pybind11

New to pybind - read the documentation but I do not grasp how to apply it to 2D arrays.

I have two arrays storing 3d coordinates `shape = (10,3)`

```
a = np.zeros(shape=(10,3))
b = np.ones(shape=(10,3)) * 3
c = a + b
```

Now, using pybind, how do I perform this operation in C++ working on the numpy arrays?

In some documentations I read to access the elements with the `[]` operator, in others with `()`. 
How do assign the 3D vector? 
How would I get the pointer to the array element to use strides for assignment - or does it have an operator?

Comment: I don't get what you are asking. It probably depends on how to treat these using C++. E.g. as std-vector or for example as Eigen-based matrices/arrays. These both accept different styles of indexing. Your example also consists of 2d-arrays only. What 3d-vector (which also sounds bad in a mathematical way) are you talking about?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

PyBind is awesome, shout out to the authors/maintainers!
You have an almost working example [here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html?highlight=numpy#arrays).

Adapted to your problem it would give something like (edited answer after El Dude's comment):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>


namespace py = pybind11;


py::array_t<double> add_arrays(py::array_t<double> input1, py::array_t<double> input2) {
  py::buffer_info buf1 = input1.request();
  py::buffer_info buf2 = input2.request();

  if (buf1.size != buf2.size) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Input shapes must match");
  }

  /*  allocate the buffer */
  py::array_t<double> result = py::array_t<double>(buf1.size);

  py::buffer_info buf3 = result.request();

  double *ptr1 = (double *) buf1.ptr,
         *ptr2 = (double *) buf2.ptr,
         *ptr3 = (double *) buf3.ptr;
  int X = buf1.shape[0];
  int Y = buf1.shape[1];

  for (size_t idx = 0; idx < X; idx++) {
    for (size_t idy = 0; idy < Y; idy++) {
      ptr3[idx*Y + idy] = ptr1[idx*Y+ idy] + ptr2[idx*Y+ idy];
    }
  }
 
  // reshape array to match input shape
  result.resize({X,Y});

  return result;
}


PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
        m.doc() = "Add two vectors using pybind11"; // optional module docstring

        m.def("add_arrays", &add_arrays, "Add two NumPy arrays");
}
```

That I built on linux with python2.7 and gcc v5.4 using (I had to use a slightly different command than provided in the doc, because Python.h wasn't found, hence I added the link to python 2.7)

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7 `python -m pybind11 --includes` example.cpp -o example`python-config --extension-suffix
```

And you'd call it from python with

```
import numpy as np
import example # [bad] name I chose for my compiled module

a = np.zeros((10,3))
b = np.ones((10,3)) * 3 
c = example.add_arrays(a, b)

print c
```

Hope it helps.

---

EDIT - I've created a [github repository](https://github.com/cjaques/pybind_examples) containing a few complete examples based on PyBind11 that should compile on all platforms.

Comment: Reshape should be possible by adjusting size & strides in the buffer object?

Comment: You're right, I missed it but there's a `resize` function on the `array_t` itself, I was trying to look into `buffer_info`. I'll edit my answer for the change, thank you.

Comment: Well, I found the example code before the post and the solution before your reply... But here you are.

Comment: I get a compilation error on this line: py::buffer_info result = py::array_t<double>(buf1.size);

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake, it should be `py::array_t<double> result = py::array_t<double>(buf1.size);` I'll edit the answer. 
You can find this code on [my github page](https://github.com/cjaques/pybind_examples)

Comment: I get a strange problem with this approach! Basically the index positions of values in my arrays `a` and `b` get shuffled around, so `c` has the right values, but not in the right places. Any clue how to order the value positions in memory so this doesn't happen?

Comment: Strange indeed. Do you have this shuffle using exactly this example? If not, can you print the type of data you send from python to C++?

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: I just fixed it, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use the buffer class.  It's well hidden / convoluted into the documentation and examples, but it's mentioned (@Christian 's post).

Buffers contain a pointer to the data as well as strides and others array parameters. Essentially the numpy header accessed through `request` method. Easy to use from there on, but finding it is bit of a pain since the example uses beautiful `C11` `auto` type to explain this usage.